# How to make an installer for a python program

Tags: python, user-interface, windows-installer

Is it possible to have someone not have python installed, double click on my installer and through that get an executable, the python, and the needed libraries?

For that I would probably also want to know, if I can type anything but `python path/file.py` to run the python script. Because for that you would need to add the python installation to path. And is there a way to bypass this? To type something else instead of `python` like manually type the location where the executable is or so?

My boss asked me this today. Don’t think that’s a common task to do with python but if I know how to do that with python, I for one can do it with python and I will also easier understand how one normally writes installers and programs with guis and such. I do like python though.

I guess this is not an easy question. I really am interested though. If you can only answer the second question, I would also be very grateful because then i can figure out the rest I think.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. This might be useful: https://net2.com/how-to-create-an-executable-from-a-python-program/

Comment: There's a difference between creating a executable from a Python script and installing it on a system — not all executables need to be installed in order to be run.

Comment: I just thought that you would not only need the executable but also the libraries. I will try suggested solutions and see what happens. Big thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Im no expert, but I think pyinstaller takes care of the dependencies and libraries the code needs

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyinstaller to create an executable. `pip install pyinstaller` in cmd.

Then cd into the directory where your file is, and type `pyinstaller --onefile filename.py`